# 'Unfortunately, app has stopped' is shown twice on the device and 'Application terminated' in android studio with no error being shown

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, logcat

I am developing an app using Android Studio.

The problem is that app gets crashed twice within few minutes of running it and besides `Application terminated.` and normal logs no error is shown in the logcat.

Here's complete logcat:

```
02/12 22:31:34: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.abc.xxx/com.abc.xxx.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 13399 on device micromax-micromax_aq4502-2864004C04884I2
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.abc.xxx-2/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.abc.xxx, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.abc.xxx-2/lib/arm
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11281(1218KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(696KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 5MB/6MB, paused 13.077ms total 70.659ms
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:4
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 4
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/armeabi-v7a
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/armeabi
I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader p[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_hdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 198168520
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: com.abc.xxx, 1:987905869088:android:e7f50263e7b8aa58
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.getsportalapp.sportal
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbks@e551d72
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: activateApp events are being logged automatically. There's no need to call activateApp explicitly, this is safe to remove.
I/GAC: Building GoogleApiClient
I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.15.167
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 824779068
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/signedIn: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:ShXMXdc5kHUQZWG3lGudJtt2
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:5
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 5
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/getInvitation: getInvitation: no deep link found.
D/called: again
D/cLat: 2.8418744
D/cLng: 8.7791019
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at geofire to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at geofire to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at geofire to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "g"' at geofire to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance
W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000010/n/armeabi
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite:12
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.piccard.dynamite, version >= 12
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000010/n/armeabi
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 8 for video/mp4v-es
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 53.0.2785.124 (code 278512400)
D/diffAnother: -6283000
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 5738-5744)
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {611ead6}
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 13399
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:8 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:9
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager, version >= 9
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.
W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 213ms
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 45000 milliseconds from now.
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 13399
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
D/diffAnother: 1129000
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
D/diffAnother: -6300000
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 13399
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 45000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=29568, _sc=MainActivity, _si=-6311178554893906199}]
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 824808635
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
W/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: activateApp events are being logged automatically. There's no need to call activateApp explicitly, this is safe to remove.
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
D/call1: called
D/call2: called
D/call1: called
D/call2: called
D/error1: ERROR1
D/error1: ERROR1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
V/RenderScript: 0xb8457a88 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
Application terminated.
```

I tried integrating crashlytics but even it doesn't show any error when the app crashes in this manner.

**The question** is how will I be able to fix the error if I don't even know what the error is?

Please help me with this.

Comment: please post your log cat..!

Comment: @shobhit done. please see edited question.

Comment: try to run LogCat in command-line? You might be able to see the error: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to your ad view.

In last line it is showing that ad  is not visible.